# How can i get value ItemSum by ItemID in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have json return:

```
{ "items": [ { "ItemID": 810, "ItemSum": 2 }, { "ItemID": 902, "ItemSum": 5 } ], "es": "", "ec": 0 }
```

How can I get value ItemSum by ItemID in php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get value ItemSum by ItemID in php ?

You need to go through the `items` and look for the `ItemID`, e. g.:

```
$object = json_decode('{ "items": [ { "ItemID": 810, "ItemSum": 2 },
                                    { "ItemID": 902, "ItemSum": 5 } ], "es": "", "ec": 0 }');

function getSumbyID($object, $ID)
{
    foreach ($object->items as $item) if ($item->ItemID == $ID) return $item->ItemSum;
}

echo getSumbyID($object, 902), "\n";
```

Comment: My correct one:
$json = '{ "items": [ { "ItemID": 810, "ItemSum": 2 }, { "ItemID": 902, "ItemSum": 5 } ], "es": "", "ec": 0 }';

$object = json_decode($json);

function getSumbyID($object, $ID)
{
    foreach ($object[items] as $item) if ($item[ItemID] == $ID) return $item[ItemSum];
}

echo getSumbyID($object, 902), "\n";

//return:
5

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
$result = json_decode('{ "items": [ { "ItemID": 810, "ItemSum": 2 }, { "ItemID": 902, "ItemSum": 5 } ], "es": "", "ec": 0 }');
foreach($result->items as $item) {
    var_dump($item->ItemSum);
}
```

Also, definitely read what's at the link @Paul Crovella commented with.